# Analysing merge sort complexity

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o, mergesort

The code I wrote is as follows:

```
def merge(A, B): #merging two sorted lists
   index_a = index_b = 0
   result = []
   while(index_a < len(A) and index_b < len(B)):
       if(A[index_a] <= B[index_b]):
           result += [A[index_a]]
           index_a += 1
       else:
           result += [B[index_b]]
           index_b += 1
   if(index_a != len(A)):#adds all remaining elements
       result += A[index_a:]
   elif(index_b != len(B)):
       result += B[index_b:]
   return result

def merge_sort(L):
   if(len(L) == 0 or len(L) == 1):
       return L
   else:
       a = merge_sort( L[:len(L)/2] )
       b = merge_sort( L[len(L)/2:] )
       return merge(a , b)
```

So I can understand the complexity of merge_sort function as shown above is log(n) for each recursive call. What I was slightly confused is in the merge function the number of steps taken, first the two assignments but after that I dont know how to get the number of steps taken in the worst case because I cant think of where to stop in the length of A or B and the later addition.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you've structured your merge, while slightly more performant, makes it trickier to see the complexity. Try this:

```
def merge(A, B): #merging two sorted lists
   index_a = index_b = 0
   result = []
   while(index_a < len(A) or index_b < len(B)): # NOTE OR
       if index_a < len(A) and (index_b == len(B) or A[index_a] <= B[index_b]): # NOTE EXTRA CONDITIONS
           result += [A[index_a]]
           index_a += 1
       else:
           result += [B[index_b]]
           index_b += 1
   return result

def merge_sort(L):
   ...
```

Here I've replaced the "then dump the rest" code with a change to the while-loop condition (allowing it to run until both input lists are sorted), and an extra condition to the if-statement to make that work properly. If you assume (as is normal) that concatenating two arrays is O(n) in the size of the second array, the algorithmic complexity is unchanged by this modification. (It's unchanged even if you assume that that's constant time, but it's slightly more complicated to explain.)

Now you can see that the number of times the while-loop is executed is exactly equal to the sum of the length of the lists. This way there's no "worst case".

Comment: Ah yes this works. I was thinking of which condition to use with or. Thanks.btw is there any way i can get the complexity from the earlier code?

Comment: @PavanKumar since the minimum number of while-iterations is equal to the length of the *smaller* list passed to `merge`, and since `merge_sort` always calls `merge` with (mostly) equal list lengths, the "best case" is just a constant factor of 2 better than the worst case, which has no effect on the big-O.

Comment: I think I understand. I was picturing the best case scenario to have the first list in merge with all elements less than the second one means there will be k*n/2 steps in the while loop and 3 steps in the end. Regardless the big-O remains the same. Is this correct?

Comment: @PavanKumar Yes, that's correct. (The three extra steps can be disregarded.)

Comment: Much appreciated for the help. Thanks :)

Comment: @PavanKumar Don't forget to upvote/accept the answer.

Comment: Ah yes was still new to the site. I did now.